# Why does printf output characters instead of data?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, printf

Why does printf output characters instead of data?
Looking at the code, you can relatively understand what I want to do, but it is unclear why the output is like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(const std::string& name, uint16_t old)
        : m_Name(name)
        , m_Old(old) 
    {
    }

public:
    std::string GetName() const { return m_Name; }
    uint16_t GetOld() const { return m_Old; }

private:
    std::string m_Name;
    uint16_t m_Old;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> person = { Person("Kyle", 26), Person("Max", 20), Person("Josiah", 31) };
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < person.size(); ++i)
    {
        printf("Name: %s Old: %u\n", person[i].GetName(), person[i].GetOld());
    }
    return 0;
}


> // output
>     Name: Ь·╣ Old: 1701607755 
>     Name: Ь·╣ Old: 7889229 
>     Name: Ь·╣ Old: 1769172810
```

Comment: You need to use `std::string::c_str()` to print a `std::string` with "%s" in `printf`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `std::cout` which supports printing `std::string` as is.

Comment: @wohlstad do it as an answer, I want to confirm

Comment: In case if you build the code with `-Wall` or `-W3` (MSVC) you get a warning with explanation, that `%s` is not compatible to `std::string`

Comment: You should also cast the result of calling `GetOld()` to `unsigned`, since `%u` expects this type. Much simpler to just use `std::cout`/ `std::format`, since `printf` doesn't work well with fixed-size integral types...

Comment: @fabian or, you can use `%hu` instead, then no cast is needed

Comment: OT: Note that returning `std::string` from `GetName()` is inefficient, and usually unnecessary if you don't want to work with the copy of the string. Returning `const std::string&` may make more sense in this regard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not sure if the standard imposes an upper bound on the size of `unsiged short`. At least on https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types I didn't find such a statement at first glance. It's likely that your approach would work for most, if not all compilers out there though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) with `"%s"` requires a `(const) char*` (or something that decays into a `(const) char*`, like `(const) char[]`).

[`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has a [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method which returns a `char const*` that you can pass to `printf()`.

Therefore, your `printf()` line should be:

```
printf("Name: %s Old: %hu\n", person[i].GetName().c_str(), person[i].GetOld());
```

Note: I also changed `%u` to `%hu` - see [@RemyLebeau's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388932/#comment127881679_72388932).

Alternatively, you can use C++'s [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) stream to print the `std::string` as-is:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Name: " << person[i].GetName() << " Old: " << person[i].GetOld() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::printf` is a function from the C standard library. It does not know about the `std::string` class. You need to supply a C string (`const char*`) to `%s`. You can do that by calling the `std::string::c_str()` method.

```
printf("Name: %s Old: %u\n", person[i].GetName().c_str(), person[i].GetOld());
```